# Colon separated contents in a text file

Tags: c

I need a C program which can read contents from a text file and the contents in the file are colon separated as shown

```
CatId;1;CatName;CLOTHS;Prefix;CH;ActiveStatus;Y;......
```

So can any one suggest a best and simple logic to read the contents and store it in a buffer?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Minor point, Kumar, `;` is called a *semicolon*. This falls into the class of file called 'Comma Separated Value'

Comment: Next time make an attempt then ask for solutions to your problem.

Comment: @pavium iam sorry.. just in a horry i have misspelt that..

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if it's the best way to do it but I would:

- Use `fgets` to read the file line by
  line
- Use `strtok` to tokenize the string
  (or do it manually depending on how
  lazy I feel)

Something like this:

```
char *p;
while (fgets(line, MAXLINE, fp)) {
    p = strtok(line, ";");
    while (NULL != p) {
         /* p is a token */
        p = strtok(NULL, ";");
    }
}
```

Comment: The strtok function is exactly what he needs. -1 for writing the function for the OP(done his homework) and +1 for the code so....

Comment: @Dark Star1 I used to have a slackware box named like you :-)

Comment: 4LL UR sl4ckw4r3 b0x3s R b3l0ng 2 m3 :P